# submit form and render new page React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I want to submit a form, which I have, and then render a new page, in react. HEre's what I have:

```
axios
  .post('http://localhost:3000/create', book)
  .then(() => console.log('Created'))
  .then(() => this.props.history.push('/home'))
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

so `axios` sends a post request with the data to the backend, and then I try to direct my app to `/home` but it doesn't do anything, doesn't go there. how do I fix this?

Comment: Why is there 2 thens? Can't you write the push home route in first then. The second then isn't a thenable as the previous doesn't return any response

Comment: ok I just took the console log out and it still didn't work either...

Comment: which is the react-router-dom version you are using ?